# Keep receiving BCDEdit "The system cannot find file specified" errors

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, bcd, bcdedit

I'm currently having a huge problem where I cannot play CS:GO due to an issue with enabling/disabling DEP, Kernel Debugging and Kernal Integrity through BCDEdit in 
Command Prompt.

According to [**THIS GUIDE**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2117-ILZV-2837) I must separately input the following commands into CMD:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue nointegritychecks 
bcdedit /deletevalue loadoptions 
bcdedit /debug off 
bcdedit /deletevalue nx
```

An alternative to the last command is:

```
bcdedit /set {current} nx AlwaysOn
```

However every time I attempt one of these commands I receive the error:

```
An error occurred while attempting to reference the specified entry. 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

The original issue is that I'm being kicked by the anti-cheat known as "VAC" presumably due to a vulnerability in the settings of my PC. For some reason I can be kicked randomly within 30 minutes to 2 days of the last kick.

All this has been run in both standard and elevated Command Prompt with Administrator permissions. My understand of commands is relatively limited and any suggestions or guidance would be well appreciated.

EDIT: I've killed nearly every third party process before trying. Programs have little effect. This problem lies with the BCD

Comment: may be you just have some *bad* programs, like antiviruses, etc: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289

Comment: I wish it was that simple but I've tried opening it with virtually all 3rd party services and programs/processes closed, however the error still happens.

Comment: try easybcd http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Answer (score -2):

The V.A.C. people need to fix it, apparently powershell, a windows program can cause this as well. You cant uninstall powershell.
 I get the same errors when using cmd in admin mode.